# Case Assignment Community Portal. Insufficient access rights on cross-reference id when enabling email

Tags: apex, trigger, community, case

I have a trigger to assign cases when they are entered in our community portal.  It works great for guest users, and for regular salesforce users, but for users in the community users profile I get an error

> insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Here is the code from in the trigger. It is an after insert trigger:

```
Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
dmo.AssignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;

for(Case c : caseList) {

    c.setOptions(dmo);   
    c.Process_Case_Assignment__c = true;
}

update caseList;
```

Now the interesting thing here is that it does not fail when I create a test and run the code as a community user, but it fails in the actual community site.
Also it does not fail if I remove the line

> dmo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;

If I remove that line it works, the case is assigned but then the emails are never sent.  Also I think it was working when I first wrote the trigger months ago, and it is failing now.

Any ideas?

Comment: The workaround for me right now is to do this processing in a @future method, and that seems to work.  I would love to hear any ideas about potential causes for the error though.